# Port forwarding suddenly stopped working on TP-Link router (Archer AX1500)

Tags: networking, wireless-router, port-forwarding, webserver, port

Over the last few hours or so, my ports have been timing out one by one, until as of a few minutes ago, they all stopped working. Restarting the router through various methods only seems to have made the problem worse.

First my mail ports dropped out, then my Minecraft server port, and now finally, my web ports dropped out (with the same protocol seeming to drop all at once, as I have 4 http/https ports which all dropped at the same time)

This seems like a common TP-Link problem, but there's no concrete fix (especially when the router did this literally on its own out of nowhere while I was away)

Comment: Are you sure it's the router and not the ISP? It's the "same protocol" part that sounds very out-of-place.

Comment: there was a small point in time where trying to connect showed an error page generated by the router itself about remote management being disabled or something like that, before port 443 worked again for like a minute before completely dying

Comment: Have you tried a firmware update? (And remote management should be disabled, if at all possible, to reduce the chance of it being taken over by bad people.)

Comment: both are, and it seems to be a mixture of both the router being weird and my ISP

Comment: What model router? Are you connecting via WiFi or wired? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc the router model is in the title, and it's over WiFi as I don't have a spare ethernet cable

Comment: If your port-forwarding is correct, the router may be failing.